# DL380G9 shutdown error = NMI: Channel Check / IOCHK

Tags: windows

**`DL380G9 shutdown error = NMI: Channel Check / IOCHK`**

- Product Name: HP PROLIANT DL380 G9 SERVER
- Operating System: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Dear all,

Each time I **Shutdown** from windows session, after the shutdown message, a front face **LED** turn into **red** and **blue screen** displays:

**`Hardware malfunction - Call your hardware vendor for support - NMI: Channel Check / IOCHK The system has halted`**

Windows seems to be terminated correctly because at the following reboot no error or warning message appears.

Note : If select Windows "Restart" does not give the error.

Do HP engineers or anybody have experience on this trouble ?

Thanks to all